# CakePHP 3 hasMany assotiation remains dirty after save and not saving

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

There are many questions about saving hasMany assotiation in CakePHP, i have read all of them but still haven't clue why i can't save it.

CakePHP docs say

> By default all first level entities will be saved.

in searh of problem i have added `['associated' => ['Sections']]` to `patchEntity()` and `save()` for sure.

**EventsController.php**

```
  101  public function edit($id = null)
  102  {
  103    if ($id) {
  104      $event = $this->Events->get($id, [
  105        'contain' => ['Sections']
  106      ]);
  107    }
  108    if ($this->request->is(['patch', 'post', 'put'])) {
  109      debug($this->request->getData());
  110      $event = $this->Events->patchEntity($event, $this->request->getData(), ['associated' => ['Sections']]);
  111      debug($event);
  112      if (empty($event->member_id)) $event->member_id = $this->Auth->user('id');
  113
  114      if ($this->Events->save($event, ['associated' => ['Sections']])) {
  115        debug($event);
```

Result of this code:

**src/Controller/EventsController.php (line 109)**

```
[
  'slug' => 'ks_2018',
  'start_date' => '2018-05-31 23:43:00',
  'sections' => [
    (int) 0 => [
      'id' => '9',
      'slug' => 'general',
      'description' => 'retwyetu'
    ]
  ]
]
```

**/src/Controller/EventsController.php (line 111)**

```
object(App\Model\Entity\Event) {

  'id' => (int) 9,
  'slug' => 'ksvelo45_2018',
  'start_date' => object(Cake\I18n\Time) {

    'time' => '2018-05-31T23:43:00+03:00',
    'timezone' => 'Europe/Kiev',
    'fixedNowTime' => false

  },
  'member_id' => (int) 1,
  'created' => object(Cake\I18n\Time) {

    'time' => '2018-03-06T05:37:04+00:00',
    'timezone' => 'UTC',
    'fixedNowTime' => false

  },
  'modified' => object(Cake\I18n\Time) {

    'time' => '2018-03-09T01:31:50+00:00',
    'timezone' => 'UTC',
    'fixedNowTime' => false

  },
  'sections' => [
    (int) 0 => object(App\Model\Entity\Section) {

      'id' => (int) 9,
      'event_id' => (int) 9,
      'slug' => 'general',
      'description' => 'retwyetu',
      '[new]' => false,
      '[accessible]' => [
        'event_id' => true,
        'slug' => true,
        'description' => true,
        'event' => true,
        'participants' => true
      ],
      '[dirty]' => [
        'description' => true
      ],
      '[original]' => [
        'description' => null
      ],
      '[virtual]' => [],
      '[errors]' => [],
      '[invalid]' => [],
      '[repository]' => 'Sections'

    }
  ],
  '[new]' => false,
  '[accessible]' => [
    'slug' => true,
    'start_date' => true,
    'member_id' => true,
    'member' => true,
  ],
  '[dirty]' => [
    'start_date' => true
  ],
  '[original]' => [
    'reg_start_date' => object(Cake\I18n\Time) {

      'time' => '2018-05-12T23:42:00+00:00',
      'timezone' => 'UTC',
      'fixedNowTime' => false

    },
    'start_date' => object(Cake\I18n\Time) {

      'time' => '2018-05-31T23:43:00+00:00',
      'timezone' => 'UTC',
      'fixedNowTime' => false

    }
  ],
  '[virtual]' => [],
  '[errors]' => [],
  '[invalid]' => [],
  '[repository]' => 'Events'

}
```

**/src/Controller/EventsController.php (line 115)**

```
object(App\Model\Entity\Event) {

  'id' => (int) 9,
  'slug' => 'ksvelo45_2018',
  'start_date' => object(Cake\I18n\Time) {

    'time' => '2018-05-31T23:43:00+03:00',
    'timezone' => 'Europe/Kiev',
    'fixedNowTime' => false

  },
  'member_id' => (int) 1,
  'created' => object(Cake\I18n\Time) {

    'time' => '2018-03-06T05:37:04+00:00',
    'timezone' => 'UTC',
    'fixedNowTime' => false

  },
  'modified' => object(Cake\I18n\Time) {

    'time' => '2018-03-09T01:43:05+02:00',
    'timezone' => 'Europe/Kiev',
    'fixedNowTime' => false

  },
  'sections' => [
    (int) 0 => object(App\Model\Entity\Section) {

      'id' => (int) 9,
      'event_id' => (int) 9,
      'slug' => 'general',
      'description' => 'retwyetu',
      '[new]' => false,
      '[accessible]' => [
        'event_id' => true,
        'slug' => true,
        'description' => true,
        'event' => true,
        'participants' => true
      ],
      '[dirty]' => [
        'description' => true
      ],
      '[original]' => [
        'description' => null
      ],
      '[virtual]' => [],
      '[errors]' => [],
      '[invalid]' => [],
      '[repository]' => 'Sections'

    }
  ],
  '[new]' => false,
  '[accessible]' => [
    'slug' => true,
    'start_date' => true,
    'member_id' => true,
    'member' => true,
  ],
  '[dirty]' => [],
  '[original]' => [],
  '[virtual]' => [],
  '[errors]' => [],
  '[invalid]' => [],
  '[repository]' => 'Events'

}
```

Answer (score 1):

While i asking this question i have found a solution.

I have noted that `accessible` array doesn't contain `sections` entry.

It's because I have added `Sections` table when `Events` was ready and edited, so not baked again.

**Model\Entity\Event.php**

```
protected $_accessible = [
    'slug' => true,
    'start_date' => true,
    'member_id' => true,
    'member' => true,
    'sections' => true          <- added
];
```

After that assotiations was saved correctly.